# Finite field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and let $P$ be the unique maximal ideal of $K$. We have $\mathbb{Z}_p\subseteq\mathcal{O}_K$ and that $P\cap\mathbb{Z}_p=p\mathbb{Z}_p$. The claim is that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p$. Why is this true? If we let $x+p\mathbb{Z}_p\in\mathbb{F}_p$ I'm not sure why this implies the result.

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_p$ the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: So I can't apply the lattice isomorphism theorem since the quotients are different.

Comment: Something's a bit strange in the question. I would say that $K$ should be a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $P$ the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Anyway, consider the composition of the following ring homomorphisms:
$$\Bbb{Z}_p\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_K/P,$$ where the first map is the inclusion and the second is the natural projection. As you saw, the kernel of the composition is $P\cap\Bbb{Z}_p=p\Bbb{Z}_p$. Therefore we get a homomorphism of fields $\Bbb{F}_p\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K/P$. Such homomorphisms are always injective implying the claim.